# Get union type of values of a const enum in Typescript

Tags: typescript

In my project some forms a defined by the backend; they are transfered as a JSON object and parsed in a module of the application. The type of field is defined by a specific field (`fieldType`) which exists for every field; every other option depends on the type. In our application we defined interfaces for each type. All valid strings for `fieldType` are defined in the union type of strings `FieldType`.

I would like to define a `const enum` with an all valid field types. Unfortunately I do not know how to avoid duplication of strings (in the `enum` and the union type). I tried to replace the type with the enum and the type-definition with derived type from the enum (`type FieldType =  typeof FieldTypesEnum[keyof typeof FieldTypesEnum]`) but both break some parts of the application.

I tried to create an examle here:

```js
// what the application receives from the backend:
const fromBackend = [
  {
    fieldType: 'input',
  },
  {
    fieldType: 'PASSWORD',
    maskChar: '*'
  }
];

// what I would like to add:
const enum FieldTypesEnum {
  INPUT = 'input',
  PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD'
}

// what is currently defined in the application
type FieldType = 'input' | 'PASSWORD'; 
// would lile to replaces this with s.th.like 
//type FieldType =  typeof FieldTypesEnum[keyof typeof FieldTypesEnum]

interface FieldBase {
  fieldType: FieldType; 
  required?: boolean;
}

interface InputField extends FieldBase{ // is marked as invalid if type FieldType = typeof FieldTypesEnum[keyof typeof FieldTypesEnum]; - error: Types of property 'fieldType' are incompatible.
  fieldType: 'input';
  maxLength?: number,
}

interface PasswordField extends FieldBase {
  fieldType: 'PASSWORD';
  maskChar?: string;
}

type AllFieldTypes = InputField | PasswordField;

// what we use in the application 
function foo(field: AllFieldTypes) {
  if (field.fieldType === 'PASSWORD') { // would like to use FieldTypesEnum.PASSWORD
     // ... do stuff
  }
}



const fields:AllFieldTypes[] = [
  {
    fieldType: 'input', // breaks if I use fieldType: FieldTypesEnum; in FieldBase and using FieldTypesEnum.XYZ in the extending classes
                        // which is odd because I would not be able to debug problems by pasting the response into code without replacing each occurrence of strings with elements with enum members.
    maxLength: 5,
  },
  {
    fieldType: FieldTypesEnum.INPUT,
    required: true,
  },
  {
    fieldType: 'PASSWORD',
    maskChar: '*'
  }
];
```

I noted which compiler errors I get on which change.

Comment: The question details don't explain whether the specialized inlining behavior of [const enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums) during compilation is actually required — and — based on the provided details (specifically the comments in the code) it sounds like you don't actually want to use an enum at all. The compiler will not allow substituting of literal values in place of expected enum members.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77544299/get-union-type-of-values-of-a-const-enum-in-typescript#comment136706234_77544299) If that behavior is required, then using an [object instead of an enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums) is a recommended approach ([example](https://tsplay.dev/wXyZkN)). If that addresses your question, I can write it as an answer — if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jsejcksn, you are right - using _const object_ was the point I was missing. Thank you. Please write you solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums):

> In modern TypeScript, you may not need an enum when an object with [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) could suffice.
>
> …
>
> The biggest argument in favour of this format over TypeScript’s `enum` is that it keeps your codebase aligned with the state of JavaScript, and [when/if](https://github.com/rbuckton/proposal-enum) enums are added to JavaScript then you can move to the additional syntax.

Here's an example of the code you showed using an object to fulfill the programming intent:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYgSwKYBsAmAVAngByTAXhgG8AoGGASQDkAFAVQwC4YAiBMHAVylYBpyMWgEEAyqIDqAeQBKAERasR46fP6kAvjACGEGKEhQA3KVJRc+RKkwXCMc3hAAzeMnTY8AbQDWSLM-sLAKt3CwBdEwoYAHpogD0AflMOKCQAJydtYEs3NAAhXXwyCidcjyQWEJs8SJg0pABHLgR6tASWACMQEBQkbTATDWSwVIys-EpOHiqYJAAPVLA0PSqCiCLBUutyxQ5uXlqAW205gBkkMABzKAALdpgwLkOO9MHh0czsoV0IAHcQNJoGbzRbLVzWNYbEplCyKZSSWRyVhHXTeADCN20aXu0DSHEubzMtmEKBQVXKeiIk32MwAPt8IH8AUDciZSE4uGBgFAEOAYE5ugAKLboFgkskwvAQACUJEECBcwtyADoRdV8ARNeDQnhlfDVHJZcUomrlccIOjMWlalEorFEqZbabjmcLtcbkYYtEYABROZ4blINCzNJpAEwQC8G4BZHcEQyGpFiMF+mNgt3w2hwOBQCGA2h5fPq2QQADckHonGHDvYbvgOllfEsmKQDNB+ZWCsAG8GiJ5BMbodtYWw9jx1BQNAIKP3+ZKKmx9Yix1FzZasYoAFRLiekMIwCB5hAQLZ6cXkiwQTwRUwt2BqykwXtTwQDnVz9hTXiT5cnc5XW4sABWL9tyfJ1Z0qWdlRoBgMC-Ch6iaFogxYKA0i4JBgK-ac1R2ecxARNQ4JgFcMTXNhN0wnc9wPI9kBPUkzylS8TCAA)

```ts
const FieldType = {
  INPUT: "input",
  PASSWORD: "PASSWORD",
} as const;

type FieldType = typeof FieldType[keyof typeof FieldType];
   //^? type FieldType = "input" | "PASSWORD"

interface FieldBase {
  fieldType: FieldType;
  required?: boolean;
}

interface InputField extends FieldBase {
  fieldType: "input";
  maxLength?: number;
}

interface PasswordField extends FieldBase {
  fieldType: "PASSWORD";
  maskChar?: string;
}

type AllFieldTypes = InputField | PasswordField;

function foo(field: AllFieldTypes) {
  if (field.fieldType === FieldType.PASSWORD) {
    field.maskChar;
        //^? (property) PasswordField.maskChar?: string | undefined

    field.maxLength; /* Expected error 
          ~~~~~~~~~
    Property 'maxLength' does not exist on type 'PasswordField'. (2339) */
  }
}

// what the application receives from the backend:
const fromBackend = [
  {
    fieldType: "input",
  },
  {
    fieldType: "PASSWORD",
    maskChar: "*",
  },
] satisfies AllFieldTypes[];

const fields = [
  {
    fieldType: "input",
    maxLength: 5,
  },
  {
    fieldType: FieldType.INPUT,
    required: true,
  },
  {
    fieldType: "PASSWORD",
    maskChar: "*",
  },
] satisfies AllFieldTypes[];
```

Note that `FieldType` is both a *value* and a *type* in the code above, and this closely emulates the behavior of [string enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) in the type system.