# How to associate a set of enum values into generic type

Tags: typescript

```
export interface VLabel<T = string> {
  value: T
  label: string
}

export enum Vehicle {
  Car = 'CAR',
  Bicyle = 'BICYLE',
  Train = 'TRAIN',
  Scooter = 'SCOOTER',
}

export interface IModel extends VLabel<Vehicle> {}
```

To me, what I expect is `Property:value` in IModel would be `CAR | BICYLE | TRAIN | SCOOTER`

But right now its "value" is in Vehicle enum type.

I was not so sure that by Vehicle enum type, it means it is a object types or actually it means the union of what I expected already

Edit:
All answers below or suggested answer from other post gives me

```
Property:value in IModel would be Car | Bicycle | Train | Scooter
```

But what I want is below, which is the value of enum, not the key

```
Property:value in IModel would be CAR | BICYLE | TRAIN | SCOOTER
```

Comment: If you directly want a union, why not use `VLabel<'CAR' | 'BICYCLE' | 'TRAIN' | 'SCOOTER'>`?

Comment: i added more to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgNQBlMAjYAGwB4AVOAXjgGcYpkBzAPjgG8AoOOADdM5AK7AAXHGr845UhSnNWSNrwC+vXqEiw4wJKIC2BYAAsE2cnj4CAwpij04AcjsBBAEouANLIBClgCe1s4u-gCSdgCahACivrLUUJjIYdSe7hEAcokCAMrYEBCoTgwu+XYA8lXUcd5+mtrg0PDIpVi4cBEAshAAJhT6IKhI-YwExGRU+OaW1lzcTUVIzHAgUr0DQwy2AkIi4lKzFlbAAHQOUH77cgrkUgBE6MWPGlora0GbfYPkznsBMIxJJTKdrOdAtgQsAbvt5NMniRHG91EA), is doing what you expect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get union type of values of a const enum in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77544299/get-union-type-of-values-of-a-const-enum-in-typescript)

Comment: The `Vehicle` type *is* the union `'CAR' | 'BICYCLE' | 'TRAIN' | 'SCOOTER'` that you want (technically it's a nominal-ish subtype of that union). If something about this isn't working for you, please [edit] the example to demonstrate it.  It's possible you either don't really want an enum, or maybe you're looking to serialize the enum values as string literal types, etc., but without seeing a [mre] of an actual problem it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to get your expected behavior is *mapping* your `enum` values to a string literal [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) using a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) (`` `${Vehicle}` ``). However, this eliminates the purpose of the enum in this example.

```
export interface VLabel<T = string> {
  value: T;
  label: string;
}

export enum Vehicle {
  Car = "CAR",
  Bicyle = "BICYLE",
  Train = "TRAIN",
  Scooter = "SCOOTER",
}

export interface IModel extends VLabel<`${Vehicle}`> {}

const model: IModel = {
  value: "BICYLE",
  //^? VLabel<"CAR" | "BICYLE" | "TRAIN" | "SCOOTER">.value: "CAR" | "BICYLE" | "TRAIN" | "SCOOTER"
  label: "whatever",
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgNQBlMAjYAGwB4AVOAXjgGcYpkBzAPjgG8AoOOADdM5AK7AAXHGoBufnHKkKU5qyRs5AX169QkWHGBJRAWwLAAFgmzk8fAQGFMUenABEDgIIAlNwBp5ACFrAE9bVzdAgEkHAE1CAFF-eWooTGQI6m9PKIA5ZIEAZWwICFQXBjdChwB5GuoE3wDtXXBoeGRyrFw4KIBZCAATCkMQVCRBxgJiMioAAwASbnxLa1tNOa5uFpKkZjgTIeVegeHyV3shEXEpSJj4pICBAHpngD0AfmmlKg8fNzgAB93NE4okAcC3Fkcvkge5qnUGr4OAA6YRiSTuLy+OF3MFJXHQvIQ+G1eqNNzyRSzW4AdwsmFQgjQyU0ciAA)

Answer (score -1):

Using an enum within a generic class: Define an enum type within a generic class and use it as a member variable. This allows you to associate specific enum values with the generic type. For example, in Java

public class EnumSet {
private final Enum enumValue;

```
public EnumSet(Enum<T> enumValue) {
    this.enumValue = enumValue;
}

public Enum<T> getEnumValue() {
    return enumValue;
}
```

}

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question